# Binding a List to a Viewmodel using knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to MVC and knockout and JS for that matter.
I am trying to display a list of Providers using Knockout.
I have the following code to get the list of Providers

```
        public ActionResult Index()
       {
            Provider providerList = new Provider();
            IList<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();
            return View(providers);
       }
```

I have the following View

```
   @model List<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>
   @{
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
 <head>
     <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>     
        <th>Provider Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th></th>  
    </tr>

<tbody data-bind="foreach:viewmodel">
  <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Certification"></>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="del" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete');" data-bind="attr: { href: '/Provider/Delete/' + ProviderID }"> Delete </a>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>           
  </table>
  </body>
```

I have written a script to get convert the Model data into Json data.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
       url: '/Provider/jsonview',
       dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        viewmodel = ko.utils.parseJson(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
  </script>
```

I have written a jsonview action in the controller.

```
     public ActionResult jsonview()
    {
        Provider providerList = new Provider();
        List<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(providers);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But the table is not displaying the list of providers.Could you folks guide me in the right direction?

I have a JS file "Additional Scripts" that I am referencing in _layout page as shown.

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css"/>

       <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/AdditionalScripts.js"></script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

The code in the JS file is as shown

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

//alert("document ready");

var Provider =
          {
              ProviderID: ko.observable(""),
              ProviderType: ko.observable(""),
              FirstName: ko.observable(""),
              LastName: ko.observable(""),
              Certification: ko.observable(""),
              Specialization: ko.observable(""),
              SSN: ko.observable(""),
              ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
              ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
              FacilityName: ko.observable(""),
          }
              ko.applyBindings(Provider);

//A function to check if all the fields have been filled before posting the form.
function ValidatethisForm() {
    if (Provider.ProviderType() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.FirstName() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.LastName() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.Certification() === "")
        return false
    else if (Provider.Specialization() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.ContactNumber() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.ContactEmail() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.FacilityName() === "")
        return false;
    else
        return true;
   }

   //Post the form on clicking the Submit Button.
    $("#Submit").on("click", function () {
    if (ValidatethisForm()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Provider/Create",
            data: Provider
        });
    }
    });

$("#ProviderType").blur(function () {
    if ($('#ProviderType :selected').text() == "Select a Provider Type")
        alert("Please choose a Provider");
     });

   //Scripts for the First Name
      $("#FirstName").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
        $("#Err_FirstName").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_FirstName").hide();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
          });

     $("#FirstName").focusin(function () {
    if ($("#Err_FirstName").is(":visible"))
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
});

$("#FirstName").keydown(function (event) {
    //$("#Err_FirstName").hide();
    //var inputVal = $(this).val();
    //var reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/
        });

//Scripts for the Last Name
$("#LastName").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
        $("#Err_LastName").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_LastName").hide();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
         });

      $("#LastName").keypress(function () {
    //$("#Err_LastName").hide();
          });

     //Scripts for the Certification
      $("#Certification option:selected").blur(function () {
    if ($('#Certification :selected').text() == "Select a Certification")
        alert("Please choose a Certification");
         });

     //Scripts for the Specialization
        $("#Specialization option:selected").blur(function () {
        if ($('#Specialization :selected').text() == "Select a Specialization")
        alert("Please choose a Specialization");
         });

     //Scripts for SSN
     $("#SSN").blur(function () {
       if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_SSN").show();
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
    }
      else {
        $("#Err_SSN").hide();
        var SSN = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(SSN.substring(0, 3) + "-" + SSN.substring(3, 5) + "-" + SSN.substring(5));
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
       });

   $("#SSN").keypress(function () {
    //$("#Err_SSN").hide();
     });

   //Scripts for the Facility Name
     $("#FacilityName").blur(function () {
       if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_FacName").show();
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
    }
      else {
        $("#Err_FacName").hide();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
       });

   $("#FacilityName").keypress(function () {
      //$("#Err_FacName").hide();
      });

      //Scripts for the Contact Number
      $("#ContactNumber").blur(function () {
     if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_ContactNum").show();
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_ContactNum").hide();
        var ContactNum = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("(" + ContactNum.substring(0, 3) + ")" + ContactNum.substring(3, 6) + "-" +      ContactNum.substring(6));
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
    }
      });

     $("#ContactNumber").keypress(function () {
    //$("#Err_ContactNum").hide();
     });

//Scripts for the Email Address
     $("#EmailAddress").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_EmailAddress").show();
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
    }
    else {
        $("#Err_EmailAddress").hide();
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var email = $('#EmailAddress').val();
        $(this).removeClass('borderclass');
        if (!re.test(email)) {
            $("#Err_EmailAddress").show();
            $(this).addClass('borderclass');
        }
    }
    });

    $("#EmailAddress").keypress(function () {
    //$("#Err_EmailAddress").hide();
    });

      //$(function () {
     //    $('#SuccessMessage').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
    //});
     })

     function onlyAlphabets(evt) {
   var charCode;
   if (window.event)
    charCode = window.event.keyCode;  //for IE
   else
    charCode = evt.which;  //for firefox
  if (charCode == 32) //for &lt;space&gt; symbol
    return false;
if (charCode > 31 && charCode < 65) //for characters before 'A' in ASCII Table
    return false;
if (charCode > 90 && charCode < 97) //for characters between 'Z' and 'a' in ASCII Table
    return false;
if (charCode > 122) //for characters beyond 'z' in ASCII Table
    return false;
return true;
      }

      function onlyNumbers(evt) {
var charCode;
if (window.event)
    charCode = window.event.keyCode;   //if IE
else
    charCode = evt.which; //if firefox
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
    }

      function validateEmail() {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
var email = $('#EmailAddress').val();
return re.test(email)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to bind your Model to knockout. All of the data is being passed to the view already so you don't need to do an AJAX request

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Provider providerList = new Provider();
    IList<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();
    return View(providers);
}
```

The view receives a Model of type IList<Provider>

View Code:

```
@model List<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
    <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>     
        <th>Provider Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th>Specialization</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>Facility Name</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th></th>  
    </tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel"> <-- Bind it to the viewModel
<tr>
    <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Certification"></>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
    <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="del" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete');" data-bind="attr: { href: '/Provider/Delete/' + ProviderID }"> Delete </a>
    </td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>           
</table>
```

And in the script part, make sure you bind the Model from the controller to a knockout viewModel:
EDIT: Like Max suggested you don't need that AJAX call, you can just do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did help.Thanks a lot.I had to download a knockout.mapping JS file fr it to work,but its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to serialize providers manually, try to return raw data, `JsonResult` would take care of serialization.

```
return Json(DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also there are other mistakes, like
- you don't need to re-create and re-bind your viewModel
- you don't need to parse result

```
var viewmodel = {
    providers: ko.observableArray()
};
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);

$.ajax({
 url: '/Provider/jsonview',
   dataType: "json",
   type: "GET",
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (data) {
      viewmodel.providers(data);        
   },
   error: function (xhr) {
     alert('error');
   }
 });
```

[Working JsFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uEKF38)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried what you suggested.I still dont get the list of providers.

Comment: Hey,I copied your code into my view.But its still not working.I have another JS file that I am referending in the _layout page.Could that be creating an issue.

Comment: I did ,Its working perfectly fine over there .. When I copied an pasted the same code in my view,I did not get all the records.I have posted some more code in regards to where I am referencing another JS file.I was wondering if that could be creating an issue with the Ajax call.Sorry if the post has now become too long.

Comment: In the other JS file,I am binding the data to the viewmodel for creation purposes.Could that be creating an issue.

Comment: There is no way for me to send you the code I guess.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68877/discussion-between-abhishek-ks-and-max-brodin).